# Sending selected value of Drop Down List back to a Controller Action using jQuery Ajax MVC4

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to send back the value of a selected item in Drop Down List back to an Action method in my controller using jQuery Ajax in an MVC4 web application. I have a Drop Down List called MeditechDropDown and here is my jQuery function that is not quite working. I manage to reach my Action method but the value coming in is null.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $("#MeditechDropDown").change(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/PopulateEmailAddressUI",
            data: JSON.stringify('id=' + $(this).val()), // Send value of the drop down change of option
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (data) {
                // Variable data contains the data you get from the action method
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The action name is PopulateEmailAddressUI. Will someone kindly shed some light on what I am doing wrong? I know I am not writing my jQuery function correctly. Many thanks.

Comment: You try setting `dataType: 'json'` in your ajax call?

Comment: Yes, have done that now. But still null.

Comment: I have updated my answer to show my controller code if that helps any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the full WORKING jQuery script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $("#MeditechDropDown").change(function () {
        var id = $(this).find(":selected").val()
        var clientID = { "clientID" : id }
        console.log(id)
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/PopulateEmailAddressUI",
            data: JSON.stringify(clientID),
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (data) {
                // Variable data contains the data you get from the action method
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Thank you everyone and especially thank you zgood :)

Comment: I had to create object in this case called clientID. In that object, I had to use the notation { "clientID" : id } where clientID here refers to the string parameter that gets passed on to my Action method. I then did a JSON.stringify that object, I got result.

Comment: That is a very solid why of doing it -it's very readable. Watch out with `console.log` in production code because early version of IE don't know what it is and it will cause your script not to work in those shitty browsers ;)

Comment: Got rid of the console.log after posting :)

Answer (score 0):

I have written some successful jQuery ajax calls in .NET MVC4. This is what they look like:

```
$('#projectList').on('click', 'li', function () {
        pid = $(this).data('id');

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Admin/GetProject',
            data: '{ id: ' + pid + ' }',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                projectRetrieved(data);
            }
        });

    });
```

Controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult GetProject(int id) {
            string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conn"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);

            string sql = "SELECT * FROM [Portfolio] WHERE [id] = @id";
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", id));
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            conn.Open();
            da.Fill(dt);
            da.Dispose();
            conn.Close();

            return Json(objConv.DataTableToArrayList(dt), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for that. The trouble is you where you are reading in (int id) in GetProject action method, I am reading in (string clientID) in my PopulateEmailAddressUI method since it is alpha numberic. And the clientID is coming in as null.

Comment: @user3041439 I suspect that this line: `data: JSON.stringify('id=' + $(this).val())` is what is giving you problems. Assign `$(this).val()` to a variable outside of the ajax call and see if that works. If still no success try writing out your data object manually: `'{ id: "' + id + '"}'`

Comment: I have now posted my latest version of my jQuery function in my own answer. Any other thoughts please? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this:

```
     jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $("#MeditechDropDown").change(function () {
        var id=$(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/PopulateEmailAddressUI",
            data: {clientID:id},
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (data) {
                // Variable data contains the data you get from the action method
            }
        });
    });})
```

in data parameter name should be such as Controller  parameter name

Comment: Didn't work sorry. My Action method looks like: public ActionResult       PopulateEmailAddressUI(string clientID) {} and clientID is coming in as null.

Comment: then write: 
data:{clientID:id}

Comment: Thank you again, but still null :(

Comment: delete this string
`contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'`
And if not helps, look, probably in drop down contains empty  value:
<option value="" >Text</option>